# How do I give an Openstack server permissions to call the Openstack APIs?

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace-cloudfiles

I am aware of how the permission system works in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/):
By giving an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance a specific [IAM role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html), it is possible to give all programs running on that specific EC2 instance some set of permissions for accessing other AWS services (e.g. permission  to delete an EBS volume).

Is there something similar for [Openstack](https://www.openstack.org/)? If you would like a program that is running on an Openstack server to be able to programmatically make changes through the Openstack API:s, how do you solve that?

The scenario I am thinking of is this:
You create a new [Rackspace OnMetal cloud server](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/onmetal) together with an extra [Rackspace Cloud Block Storage](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/block-storage) volume, and copy a big input data file to it with scp. You log in to the server with ssh and start a long running compute job. It would be great if the compute job by itself would be able to copy the result files to [Rackspace Cloud Files](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files) and then unmount and delete the 
Rackspace Cloud Block Storage volume that was used as temporary storage  during the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rackspace's Role Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/overview-role-based-access-control-rbac) system is similar to AWS IAM roles. It lets you create users that restricted to specific APIs and capabilities. For example, a readonly cloud files user, or a cloud block storage administrator.

You could create a new user that only has access to the areas required for this compute job, e.g. cloud block storage and cloud files. Then your job would use that user's apikey to [request a token](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-block-storage/getting-started/#authentication) and call the [cloud block storage](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-block-storage/getting-started/) and [cloud files](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/getting-started/) api.

You did not mention a specific language but I recommend using an [SDK](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/#sdks), as it will handle the API specifics and quirks and get you up and running more quickly.

Comment: I see, so a "user" is not necessarily bound to a physical person. That opens up new technical solutions.

Comment: And if you're working from the command line, you'll want to use the [rack](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/rack-cli/) CLI. There's a [guide for Cloud Files](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/rack-cli/services/files/).

Comment: In the Rackspace web interface, I chose "User management" and then "Create user". Under  "Contact Information" I now need to specify "Contact type", "First Name", "Last Name" and "Email Address". Is there any convention for which values to provide if the user account is not a real person?

Comment: Thinking a bit more. I guess I'll just provide my own contact details there, although I'm creating a non-person user account.

Comment: Yes, I just put in my own contact details when making additional users.